# the call to "conclusionaryOutput(number1, number2, isASquare1, isASquare2)" is throwing an error and I'm not sure why

Tags: c++

The purpose of this program is to accept two numbers from the user, and figure out the two inputted numbers' factors and if they have any factors that are squares.

When I try to run it, it throws an error on the function call of `conclusionaryOutput()`:

> [cquery] address of function 'listSquares' will always evaluate to
> 'true'  [-Wpointer-bool-conversion]

and:

> use of undeclared identifier 'isASquare1'; did you mean 'listSquares'?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void conclusionaryOutput(int number1, int number2, bool isASquare1, bool isASquare2){
    if(isASquare1 == false && isASquare2 == false){
        cout << "Therefore the ordered pair (" << number1 << "," << number2 << ") is SWEET." << endl;
    }
    else if(isASquare1 == false && isASquare2 == false){
        cout << "Therefore the ordered pair (" << number1 << "," << number2 << ") is SOUR." << endl;
    }
    else if(isASquare1 == true && isASquare2 == false){
        cout << "Therefore the ordered pair (" << number1 << "," << number2 << ") is SALTY." << endl;
    }
    else{
        cout << "Therefore the ordered pair (" << number1 << "," << number2 << ") is BITTER." << endl;
    }
}
void listSquares(int divisor, int numOfSquares){
    if (numOfSquares !=1){
        cout << ", " << divisor;
    }
    else{
        cout << divisor;
    }  
}

void squareInquiry(int number1, int number2){
    bool containSquareFactor1;
    bool containSquareFactor2;
    int counter;
    int divisor;
    int numOfSquares;
    counter  = 2; 
    while (counter <= 70){
        divisor = counter * counter;
        if (number1 % divisor == 0){
            numOfSquares++;
            listSquares(divisor, numOfSquares);
        }
    counter++;
    }
    if (numOfSquares > 0){
        cout << number1 << " has these factors (>1) that are square: " << numOfSquares << endl;
        cout << number1 << "is not square-free" << endl;
        containSquareFactor1 = true;
    }
    else{
        cout << number1 << " has these factors (>1) that are square: (none) " << endl;
        cout << number1 << "is square-free" << endl;
        containSquareFactor1= false;
    }
    
    counter =2;
    numOfSquares =0;
    while(counter <=70){
        divisor = counter * counter;
        if (number2 % divisor == 0){
            numOfSquares++;
            listSquares(divisor, numOfSquares);
        }
        counter++;
    }
    if(numOfSquares > 0){
        cout << number2 << " has these factors (>1) that are square: " << numOfSquares << endl;
        cout << number2 << "is not square-free" << endl;
        containSquareFactor2 = true;
    }
    else{
        cout << number2 << " has these factors (>1) that are square: (none) " << endl;
        cout << number2 << "is square-free" << endl;
        containSquareFactor2= false;
    }
  conclusionaryOutput(number1, number2, isASquare1, isASquare2);
}  

int main(){

    int firstInt;
    int secondInt;
    cout << "Enter the 1st integer of the pair, between 2 and 5000: ";
    cin >> firstInt;
    while(firstInt < 2 || firstInt > 5000){
        cout << "Invalid entry, Please try again: ";
        cin >> firstInt;
    }
    cout << "Enter the 2nd integer of the pair, between 2 and 5000: ";
    cin >> secondInt;
    while(secondInt <2 || secondInt > 5000){
        cout << "Invalid entry, Please try again: ";
        cin >> secondInt;
    }
    squareInquiry(firstInt, secondInt);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `isASquare1` is not definied in `squareInquiry`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you *call* your `conclusionaryOutput` function (at the end of `squareInquiry`) you must give it the names of actual variables ***in the calling module*** rather than use the names of the parameters given in the function's definition. *(This may be a basic misunderstanding of function calling in C++ because, everywhere else in your code, you appear to use the *same* names for local variables and formal parameters.)*

So, rather than:

```cpp
conclusionaryOutput(number1, number2, isASquare1, isASquare2);
```

you should use:

```cpp
conclusionaryOutput(number1, number2, containSquareFactor1, containSquareFactor2);
```

With this change, the program will compile (but with a warning, if you're lucky) … but it (probably) won't work. What you have forgotten to do (also in the `squareInquiry` function) is to give the `numOfSquares` variable an initial value (the compiler is not forced to do this for you).

So, near the start of that function, where you declare that variable, give it an initial (zero) value:

```cpp
void squareInquiry(int number1, int number2)
{
    bool containSquareFactor1;
    bool containSquareFactor2;
    int counter;
    int divisor;
    int numOfSquares = 0;// Don't use this (below) without initializing it (to zero)
    counter = 2;
//...
```

Please feek free to ask for any further clarification and/or explanation.

Comment: Note that the first of the errors is caused by the compiler trying (and failing) to guess what you actually meant instead of `isASquare1` and `isASquare2`.